# why GDB behaves differently for x/i vs disass?

Tags: gdb, disassembly

Sometimes when attempting to disassemble a specific address using GDB's disassemble (or disass) command, it does not work. But using "examine as instruction" (or x/10i), it is able to disassemble.

Why the different behaviour?
Is it because when using disassemble, GDB has to verify the start address of the function and possibly match it against symbol?